# minikube kubernetes configuration

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am new to kubernetes Having issue while installing minikube.

```
Hypervisor: virtualbox 6
Base OS centos 7
docker version 19.03.5
kubectl version v1.16.3
minikube version  v1.5.2
```

> ```
> firewalld stopped
>
> iptables flushed
>
> selinux disabled
> ```

steps to reproduce:
step 1: intsall kubectl (using binaries)

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
chmod +x ./kubectl
mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

Step 2: install minikube

```
curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 && chmod +x minikube
install minikube /usr/local/bin
```

Step3: start minikube

```
minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

1) output:

> - minikube v1.5.2 on Centos 7.2.1511
> - Tip: Use 'minikube start -p ' to create a new cluster, or 'minikube delete' to delete this one.
> - Using the running none "minikube" VM ...
> - Waiting for the host to be provisioned ...
> - Preparing Kubernetes v1.16.2 on Docker '19.03.5' ...
> - Relaunching Kubernetes using kubeadm ...
> - X Error restarting cluster: waiting for apiserver: apiserver process never appeared

2) minikube logs:

```
* Nov 22 07:08:40 localhost.localdomain kubelet[13807]: F1122 07:08:40.236946   13807 server.go:196] failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error kubelet config file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml" was empty
 * Nov 22 07:08:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
 * Nov 22 07:08:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
 * Nov 22 07:08:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
 * Nov 22 07:08:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: kubelet.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
 * Nov 22 07:08:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
 * Nov 22 07:08:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
 * List item
```

As per my understanding `/var/lib/kubelet` directory was not created although kuberlet package is installed so is there anything wrong with the steps or do i have to dcreate these directory and files manually.

Comment: if you run it with -v8 it would give you more details in the logs :
 "start minikube minikube start --vm-driver=none -v8"

Comment: why don't you install it using a virtual driver by the way?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: @akazemis I tried using none-v8 option but not much help, i used vm-driver=none because although virtualization is enable in the virtual box settings for my VM. But in the VM itself when i check the virtulization support --> grep -E --color 'vmx|svm' /proc/cpuinfo its returning an empty string.

Comment: @jww i did not knew that, it might be a good idea browse Stack Exchange network, thanks

Comment: Make sure you have virtualization enabled. If `grep -E --color 'vmx|svm' /proc/cpuinfo` is empty output you don't have virtualization enabled.

Comment: @mansingh_stack  I rememeber when I was trying to install minikube in a VM I was having lots of issues. I mean nested VMs are troublesome, so if you install it on your host but set a vm-driver to get the minikube running on its own VM, it would much probably work.